# How to Fix (500) Internal Server Error when a Method is called in 2nd time?

Tags: c#, methods

I wrote a method in my C# program.
It's the Code:

```
    private string connect(string mypage, string myrln, string myusername , string mypassword)
    {
        WebRequest request = WebRequest.Create("http://localhost/vpn/"+mypage+".asp?prog=y&u="+myusername+"&p="+mypassword+"&rln="+myrln);
        request.Credentials = CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials;
        HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
        Stream dataStream = response.GetResponseStream();
        StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(dataStream);
        string responseFromServer = reader.ReadToEnd();
        reader.Close();
        dataStream.Close();
        response.Close();

        return responseFromServer;
    }
```

For the first time that I call this method, Everything workd ok.
But for the 2nd time, (500) Internal Server Error raise.
How can I fix this?

Error is in this line:

```
      HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
```

Comment: You are making people nervous with those .Close methods (not in a using statement).  If an exception is thrown before you close the objects, you may not release the resources quickly enough.  `using ( Stream dataStream = response.GetResponseStream())
{
   ...
}`

Comment: @agent-j: I deleted those .Closes, But error still persists.

Comment: Can you attach the exception?  (At least the type of the exception and prefereably the message and stack trace.)  And please post your new code.

Comment: @agent-j: of course dear agent-j, here is the link of image: [link](http://up.vatandownload.com/images/uvxphqyqpw7mud5e8i06.jpg)

Comment: The error is occurring on the server (most likely in the .ASP page).  Add logging to your server page so you can find out what is happening in the .asp page.

Comment: @agent-j: Thank you so much. I fixed it according to your guidance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is occurring on the server (most likely in the .ASP page). Add logging to your server page so you can find out what is happening in the .asp page.

Also, put a using around your code to make sure it is disposed if an exception is thrown.

```
    WebRequest request = WebRequest.Create("http://localhost/vpn/"+mypage+".asp?prog=y&u="+myusername+"&p="+mypassword+"&rln="+myrln);
    request.Credentials = CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials;
    string responseFromServer;
    using (HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse())
    using (Stream dataStream = response.GetResponseStream())
    using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(dataStream))
    {
       responseFromServer = reader.ReadToEnd();
    }
```